# data and open incompatibility, which alternative do I have?

Tags: inheritance, kotlin, equality, class-extensions

I am doing a [kotlin port](https://github.com/elect86/kt/tree/master/src/gli) of [gli](https://github.com/g-truc/gli) and I got stuck now

Actually I have the following

`open class Texture`

extended by several classes such as `Texture2d`

Now, `Texture` has quite some properties

```
protected val storage: StorageLinear?
protected val target: Target
protected val format: Format
protected val baseLayer: Int
protected val maxLayer: Int
protected val baseFace: Int
protected val maxFace: Int
protected val baseLevel: Int
protected val maxLevel: Int
protected val swizzles: Swizzles
```

therefore I'd like to have it as a `data` class in order to exploit the `equals()` that comes with it..

but unfortunately `data` and `open` are incompatible..(see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26444145/extend-data-class-in-kotlin))

One way I can solve it, I could write my own `equals()` method, but that would be boilerplate code and dirty, exactly two of the biggest reasons why I switched to kotlin over java

Another way, since all the `class`es extending `Texture` don't really add anything, they act kind of builders (looks cpp [`Texture2d` class](https://github.com/g-truc/gli/blob/master/gli/texture2d.hpp)), would it be that of using them as.. builders (see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36150989/1047713) from Kirill)

But since nothing comes for free, of big disadvantage of this solution is that I'd lose the possibility to have `Texture2d` as a class and `Texture2d` has a nice [operator `[]`](https://github.com/g-truc/gli/blob/master/gli/texture2d.hpp#L52) to retrieve single images of textures..

Since the kotlin community looks extremely active and supporting, I'd like to know if you have any better idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO the most practical solution would be to generate `equals` in `Texture` and be done with it.

Data classes have a very narrow application on purpose. Your example does not really fit a classical `data` class, that's why you have this problem.

Comment: Wow, I did not expected this answer to be marked )) After all, @elect, you knew it from the beginning

Comment: Well, you basically confirmed my temporary choice, so it's kind of an answer for me :p

Answer (score 1):

Using interfaces and delegation pattern:

```
interface Texture {
    fun method1()
    fun method2()
}

data class TextureImpl(val baseLayer: Int, val maxLayer: Int): Texture{
    override fun method1() {

    }
    override fun method2() {

    }
}

data class Texture2d(val impl: TextureImpl) : Texture by impl

data class Texture3d(val impl: TextureImpl) : Texture by impl
```

You initialize concrete classes like `Texture2d` with `TextureImpl` which normally would be abstract but we can't make data class abstract.

I hope I wouldn't be wrong if I say I replaced an inheritance with a composition here.

Does it make sense in your case?

Comment: I choose the `equals()` option for the moment, but your suggestion is interesting, I'll think about it, +1