# Kotlin - create setters that return class instance

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to create setters automatically that return `this`?

Tried following, but this way it's not working, but this example shows what I want to achieve:

```
var pos: Int?
    set(value) : IPosItem {
        this.pos = value
        return this
    }
```

**manual solution**

Write `setters` and `getters` myself of coure, like following:

```
var _pos: Int?
fun getPos(): Int? = _pos
fun setPos(value: Int?): IPosItem {
    _pos = value
    return this
}
```

**Question**

Can this process be automated with kotlin? Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Unless the goal is to create a Java API in Kotlin, you shouldn't need that, because simply using apply() allows avoiding repeating the variable name as you would have to do in Java, and would be idiomatic Kotlin. https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html

Comment: And if the goal is to create a Java API, then a method returning something other than void is not a setter. It's a method.

Comment: I need this because an annotation processor I use generates such types of setters, so I want to use above in my custom interface of which I tell the processor that the generated class is implementing...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking at a [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), for which you'd probably use a DSL over chained setters in Kotlin.

The easiest, built-in way is to use a "block" with [receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver) (quotation marks because [`with`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html) is a proper Kotlin function, no magic here):

```
val newThing = Thing()
with ( newThing ) {
    pos = 77
    otherValue = 93
}
```

Or, similarly:

```
val newThing = Thing().apply {
    pos = 77
    otherValue = 93
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36150989/539599) for a more elaborate example that builds immutable instances. The official documentation also has [more on this topic](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html).